# Angular 7 Show and Hide a child in an *ngFor list

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a list of events, and want to show/hide details for each event when a user clicks on the event. Unsure how to proceed. I can get ALL events to show or hide, but not single ones. Looking for the simplest answer; the ones I've found so far of SO are often exceedingly complex, usually for more complex problems than mine.

```
  <div *ngFor = "let event of events; index as i" class="event-list">
    <section class = "event-item">
        <h1 class = "event-name">{{ event.name }} </h1>
    </section>

    <!-- WANT TO SHOW THIS WHEN ABOVE SECTION ELEMENT IS CLICKED -->
    <section id="event_details_{{i}}" class="event-details">
      <p>Details</p>
    </section>
    <!-- END SHOW/HIDE SECTION -->

  </div>
```

I'm really just unsure how to proceed here. I've tried a bunch of probably Angular 1x tricks but they, unsuprisingly, didn't work. I don't want to rely on hacking  it with JQuery, I'd rather use an Angular solution. Thanks!

This is along the lines of what I've tried but I can't figure out how to assign the toggleDetails[i] in the view like that.

```
  <div *ngFor = "let event of events; index as i" class="event-list">

     <span [toggleDetails[i]] = false ]></span> // if I could do this somehow it'd work but this obviously doesn't.

    <section class = "event-item" (click)="toggleDetails[i]=!toggleDetails[i]">
      <div class="event-summary">
        <h1 class = "event-name">{{ event.name }} </h1>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- WANT TO SHOW THIS WHEN ABOVE SECTION ELEMENT IS CLICKED -->
    <section id="event_details_{{i}}" class="event-details" *ngIf="toggleDetails[i]">
      <p>Details</p>
      <p>Details</p>
      <p>And deets</p>
    </section>
    <!-- END SECTION -->

  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest way is to add another property (say `toggle`) on each `event` object within an `events` array. You can add this dynamically. And hide/show based on that.

html

```
<div *ngFor="let event of events; index as i" class="event-list">
    <section class="event-item" (click)="event.toggle=!event.toggle">
        <div class="event-summary">
            <h1 class="event-name">{{ event.name }} </h1>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- WANT TO SHOW THIS WHEN ABOVE SECTION ELEMENT IS CLICKED -->
    <section class="event-details" *ngIf="event.toggle">
        <p>Details</p>
        <p>Details</p>
        <p>And deets</p>
    </section>
    <!-- END SECTION -->

</div>
```

See this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qdonkj)

Comment: Thanks Amit!!! I knew there was something super simple. :)
Makes perfect sense and easy!

Answer (score 3):

You can create some variable (with `let` keyword) in `*ngFor` and use it in each of the `*ngFor` templates.

```
*ngFor="let item of list; let hide = false"
```

with this new state your component has no more side-effect and your events stay untouched.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list; let hide = false">
  <button (click)="hide = !hide">{{hide ? 'Show' : 'Hide'}}</button>
  <p *ngIf="!hide">{{item.id}}</p>
  <p *ngIf="!hide">{{item.name}}</p>
</div>
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngfor-toggle